# how can I add a post as an admin?

Tags: python, html, django, blogs

I have a blog app in my project with posts. I am able to create posts if I go to the admin in the link, but I want to use CRUD. so if my user is a super user another option will appear to add posts. however I am not able to because it keeps saying that it cannot find the template.`
I'm not sure what to add in the models and views. I've tried many things but it's still not working. would appreciate any help!

here is my code:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.posts, name='posts'),
    path('posts/<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail, name='post_detail'),
    # path('add_post/', views.add_post, name='add_post'),
]
```

views:

```
def posts(request):
    """ A view to show all posts, including sorting """

    posts = Post.objects.all()
    sort = None
    direction = None

    if request.GET:
        if 'sort' in request.GET:
            sortkey = request.GET['sort']
            sort = sortkey
            if sortkey == 'title':
                sortkey = 'lower_title'
                posts = posts.annotate(lower_title=Lower('title'))
            if 'direction' in request.GET:
                direction = request.GET['direction']
                if direction == 'desc':
                    sortkey = f'-{sortkey}'
            posts = posts.order_by(sortkey)

    current_sorting = f'{sort}_{direction}'

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'current_sorting': current_sorting,
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/posts.html', context)
```

Comment: Could you add error traceback

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if it can't find template then probably you have to change something in config or move template to correct folder.